# Transparency for RstDocument in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any chance to make RstDocument transparent in Kivy?

There is a dict property `colors`, which can be used for setting colors:

```
class TipRstDocument(RstDocument):
    colors = DictProperty({
        'background': '000000',
        'link': 'ce5c00',
        'paragraph': '202020',
        'title': '204a87',
        'bullet': '000000'})
```

but how to set transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is `canvas` with `rgb` property in default settings in `kivy/uix/rst.py`, so every time `RstDocument` is draw with canvas without transparency (even if you set rgba in background in `DictProperty`).

The solution for me is just delete this section in `rst.py` file and then set own `canvas` with `rgba` property (with transparency).

Answer (score 2):

Every Kivy [Widget](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) has a [Opacity](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.opacity) property that can be used to set the opacity of the widget and it's children. So you can simply do rst_doc_instance.opacity = .5 to change the opacity of the instance to 50%.

Update:
Since 1.7.2-dev RstDoc now has a background_color property that can be used to set the background color according to your preferences.

So in your case::

```
RstDocument:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, .5 # 50 translucent white
```

Comment: I missed this property, so thank you very much and +1 for very fast and simple solution. But opacity is set for whole widget (so for background, text, etc) not for only background. I found better solution for me, which you can find below.

Comment: In that case you should clarify in your question that you are only looking for transparency in the background of the RstDoc Widget, and not for the entire widget as is implied by your question. Your answer works, it also highlights a inconsistency that should be fixed in kivy itself though.

Comment: Fixed in 1.7.2-dev now you can use http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html#kivy.uix.rst.RstDocument.background_color